# Sequential iOS animation *without* blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

How might one animate a UIView *without* using block structure?  I just need to force an animation to execute immediately after it is called, and I don't have the luxury of putting the rest of my program in a completion block based on the code structure.

To be specific, right now, here is what is happening

```
while (actionsRemaining)
{
   [self performDesiredAnimation];
   ....computation ....
   [barWidget decreaseValueTo:resultOfComputation];
}
```

When I run this code, all [performDesiredAnimation] animations happen simultaneously with the 10 or so barWidgets all decreasing simultaneously.  What I want is:

performDesiredAnimation1 --> barWidget decreases --> performedDesiredAnimation2 --> barWidget decreases --> performDesiredAnimation3 --> barWidget decreases --> ... however many unknown times.

I don't know how many times because actions will get removed from actionsRemaining if the barWidget decreases past a certain value, i.e. the number of loops will depend on intermediate calculations.

To put it even more simply, what I want is the same result as I am seeing now when I call just one iteration of the loop

```
[self performDesiredAnimation];
....computation ....
[barWidget decreaseValueTo:resultOfComputation];
```

, followed by the second iteration, followed by the third, all in isolation.  Right now the animation looks fine if I comment out the loop, but they all smash together when I keep the loop there.  I just want the animations to execute sequentially from iteration to iteration, not all at once.

Comment: Using a block is recommended since it will be executed on another thread.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html

Comment: There is always the super old style of begin and commit animation as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486164/iphone-how-to-commit-two-animations-after-another)

Comment: I know, but I can't convert my animation code into blocks. For one, one of the animating widgets has animation code that I cannot access and modify.  Secondly, my own animation happens in a for-loop, and I can't readily use the block structure to tell it to execute the next animation because it happens in the next iteration.

Comment: "I don't have the luxury of putting the rest of my program in a completion block based on the code structure." I don't understand what you mean by this. What are you actually trying to achieve? What difference does it make if you use blocks or not?

Comment: Remember you can call a method on 'yourself' from inside the block.

Comment: I do understand that. When ever I see blocks I feel like traveling back into the 80th where we had to use callback functions for tasks like theese. If you want to go without blocks then you will have to live with the limitations that old style `[UIView beginAnnimations::]` and `[UIView commitAnnimations:]` come with. Meaning you will not be able to animate more than changes of frame, transformation, alpha and some colour.

Comment: re: jrturton: Well, two specific things: For one, one of the animating widgets has animation code that I cannot access and modify. i.e. I cannot wrap animation at the lowest level for one of my widgets.  Secondly, my own animation happens in a for-loop, and I can't readily use the block structure to tell it to execute the next animation because it happens in the next iteration. i.e. I am trying to achieve animation as a statement inside a loop rather than writing a block that leads somewhere else, which leads somewhere else, which leads somewhere else, ..., i.e. bad coding style

Comment: Edited my post to clarify comment to jrturton

Comment: Re: Hermann Klecker.  Actually I am okay with transformation, but the problem still happens.  Meaning, I do separate my animations inside the call to performDesiredAnimations with [UIView beginAnimations::] and [UIView commitAnimations:] but they still smash together for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Blocks are not what is causing you the problem. Your problem, I think, is your "animations in a for loop" structure.

You need to keep your animating actions in a stack, and when one is finished, pop the next one off the stack and perform that. Alternatively, check in the completion block for the animation if you need to continue, and if so, call the animating method again. Something like:

```
-(void)performAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 
                     animations:^{[self performDesiredAnimations];}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                // It's not clear what your computations are or if they take any significant time
                                CGFloat result = [self doComputations];
                                [barWidget decreaseValueTo:resultOfComputation]
                                if (needToPerformAnotherSet) // Work this out however you need to
                                {
                                    [self performAnimation];
                                }
                            };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, jrturton.  So from your code (which I am about to try), it seems like the animations and completion blocks don't need to bind tightly around the animations themselves, correct?  For example, there can be a bunch of intermediate calculations done either in performDesiredAnimations, needToPerformAnotherSet, etc., as long as the animation I want to separate out is somewhere inside the animations block, it'll finish before anything in completion runs?

Comment: Just tried it.  While the animations do seem to happen in sequence, the duration doesn't seem to be right.  I set it to like 2.0 and 3.0 and it still happens fairly bang-bang.

Comment: The code above won't execute the stuff in the completion block until the animation has finished - so whatever the duration is set to. If you do the calculations in performDesiredAnimations then they will be done immediately, but the results may not be available, or may have changed, by the time the completion block is executed. You need to be clear about what you're doing with the animations and the computations.

Comment: "performDesiredAnimations" is a simple ImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation bookended by [UIView beginAnimations] and [UIView commitAnimations], but I also set that transform duration to 1.0 second.  Likewise, in the [barWidget decreaseValueTo:] the duration of that animation is also hardwired to 3.0 seconds, hard-coded into the widget decreaseValueTo call. Does the animateWithDuration:XXX override all of those internal animation durations?

Comment: for the former, don't call an animation from within an animation block. I think what will happen is that the animation block will return immediately. You don't need to have the begin / commit if you're calling it from within the animation block.

Comment: I think I figured out why it was still bang-bang: the barDecrease animation was still jumbling with the next performDesiredAnimations, so I nested it again in a [UIView animateWithDuration:....completion^(BOOL finished), which means I have the bar decrease in the animations block of the nested call, and then the next if(NeedToPerformAnotherSet) in the completion block of the nested call.  The code looks horrible, but... it does work..

Comment: For the bar one, if you need to wait for it to finish and you don't get a completion callback or handler, you'll have to use dispatch_after or something to not call the next cycle till the bar's animation has finished.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the bar widget animation is done deep in CALayers within the bar widget class, and I don't get a completion callback (not sure how to add one either, or if I could subclass it and add it) at the moment, so I'm currently using the double animationWithDuration right now. Is dispatch_after a cleaner solution, since I'm currently essentially performingAnimation, then in outer completion block's inner animations block, decreasingBar, and finally doing the recursive call in the inner completion block.  Never used dispatch_after, but if it's better than this then I'll change it.

Comment: performSelector:afterDelay: is probably the cleanest method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
// Start the work in a background thread.

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    while (actionsRemaining) {

        // Do your calculation in the background if your code will allow you to

        [self performDesiredAnimation];
        ....computation ....

        // Back to the main thread for a chunk of code

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Or do it here if not

            [self performDesiredAnimation];
            ....computation ....

            // Finally, update your widget.

            [barWidget decreaseValueTo:resultOfComputation];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Since your loop enters the async'ed background loop on each iteration the application's main run loop will get a chance to update your UI with the value that you set in the sync'd block.